# Error calculating matrix determinant of matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matrix, octave, determinants

I have this matrix

```
A1 = [7.4011 9.8999 1.9990; 7.4011 9.8988 1.9990; 7.4011 9.8999 1.9990]

A1 =
      7.4011   9.8999   1.9990
      7.4011   9.8988   1.9990
      7.4011   9.8999   1.9990
```

but when I execute the instruction `det(A1)` I get the following error:

```
error: det: invalid dense matrix type
```

What is happening?

I tried looking in the web about this error but I have not been able to find anything.

Thanks

Comment: are you using a matlab clone (e.e. Octave)?

Comment: If I cut and paste your code Matlab R2012a returns 0.  Try clearing A1 and re-doing.

Comment: The code works for me in MATLAB R2012a, GNU Octave 3.6.1 and Scilab 5.3.3. All these return a determinant of 0. So the code seems to be correct.

Comment: One possible problem occurred to me, however not related to MATLAB specifically: in some keyboard layouts it's very easy to accidentally type an invisible character, and in Linux console this caused me some strange problems before I found it out by myself and changed my keyboard layout to avoid accidental typing of invisible non-blank characters. If copy-pasted code works for you but still you encounter the same problem (or other strange problems) every now and then when you type the code, then the problem might be an invisible typo.

Comment: Oh yes. Im using Octave. Is that the problem?

Comment: depends on the version of Octave: http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/f7ba6cfe7fb7

Comment: I'm using the newest version (0.9.2) and still have this problem.

Comment: 0.9.2?  Are you referring to Octave?  The latest version is 3.6.2 (http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html).

Comment: @kokbira that's still TBD... :) Mike, you can just send an answer "Got it, folks, thx" and accept it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend you to download the latest Octave version on http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/download.html, as said @WarrenWeckesser. It would be a issue of that old version you used.

I just installed Octave-3.6.1-mingw + octaveforge pkgs for Windows (http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Windows), and it functioned perfectly! With `det(A1)`:

```
ans = 0
```

Since at least two lines on that matrix are equals, the result determinant must be zero!